# Gamemaker: Get from which children action is called

Tags: game-maker

I've got 3 Children in 1 Parent which has "Left pressed" action. I just want to know from which child this action is called.

I try `object_index` but obviously it returns Parent index.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**: 
put in Left pressed

```
with(other) { var id = object_index; }
```

will return object child which perform this event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to guess what child object is performing the `Left Click` Event at a given step.

My answer is: instead of returning the `object_index`, because the parent's one will be returned in this case, return the actual instance `id`; then, check the `object_index` of such instance reference.

This way a child's `id` will be returned, and you can check what `object_index` such child has.

Comment: Nice ! Not really sure it was what you suggest to me but it helps me to find the solution : 
" with(other) { object_index; } " and this object_index returns the child id which perform event.